# Raton à la chaîne

Tags: choix-de-mot, phrase

What does the racist phrase abattre du raton à la chaîne mean? As in:

L’État n’assurera plus la sécurité publique dans ce pays, car l’assurer implique d’abattre du raton à la chaîne, donc la guerre raciale totale. Cet état a perdu toute force intérieure et ne retrouve un semblant d’énergie que pour s’en prendre aux Blancs.

Comment: Un terme associé: _ratonnade_. http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=551548935;

Comment: You should have mentioned this is a quote from a openly racist and nazi website.

Comment: @jlliagre It very much sounds like that indeed :-(

Comment: [We do ask that you look up the meaning of words or expressions in a dictionary first... and tell us why you find the dictionary answer unsatisfactory.](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: En formant une chaîne humaine devant des bolides qui roulent à toute allure dans les rues, ces milices peuvent assurer doublement la sécurité du public ! Si les gens derrière sputnik se joignent à eux, alors triplement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very pejorative term that has its roots in the colonization of Algeria by the French. It is to be banished from one's vocabulary as it is a term of  dehumanization expressing the utmost contempt for  human beings of  Arab  origin. It can of course be used in talking of its  usage by those that disregard this point of view.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/raton)) C. − Pop., péj. Arabe, Nord-Africain. Synon. bougnoul(e), bicot.Si (...)
> • la droite française manœuvrée par le fascisme algérien, ne barrait pas la route au leader M.R.P. [M. Pflimlin], il mesurerait ce qu'a d'irréductible la résolution de ces « désespérés » qui ont pris les armes pour n'être plus jamais les ratons et les bougnoules de personne (Mauriac, Nouv. Bloc-Notes, 1961, p. 54).

> ([Les insultes à l'égard des Arabes ou des Nord-Africains](http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/arabe2.html)) Un procédé courant du racisme est l'animalisation. Cela s'exprime d'abord dans le terme *raton* (1937) qui doit sa motivation à l'enfant initié au vol (1836) sans aucun rapport avec le monde arabe. L'Arabe est supposé voleur comme le rat (1821), mais il est aussi lié à ce qui semble le plus bas dans la création : le rat qui est associé à la saleté, à l'avarice, à la laideur. Les dérivés sont nombreux : *ratonner, ratonnade, ratonneur*. Tous sont liés au contexte de la guerre d'Algérie et perdurent.

The meaning is roughly as follows.

- slaughter arabs on a mass scale

Something interesting could be remarked upon. The use of the partitive « du » is usual in this context only in relation to the dehumanizing attitude that is being held; the person is even less considered as a human being as it is undifferentiated by being viewed as part of a mass, where individuality has no meaning. Less dehumanizing would be "abattre *des ratons* à la chaine".

Comment: I don't think "abattre _des_ ratons à la chaîne" is particularly "less" dehumanizing. Once _raton_ is used, _du/des_ makes no difference to the dehumanizing aspect of the expression.

Comment: @Frank: It doesn't change much in this context because of the scale of the insult, indeed, but grammatically LPH's remark makes sense.